# According to Hebrews 11:5, did Enoch actually die? (Compare Hebrews 11:13)

Tags: contradiction, hebrews, resurrection, death

*According to the Book of Hebrews*, did Enoch actually die?  How is this "contradiction" resolved?

Excerpted from this answer, https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/27939/6338

> By faith Enoch was translated that ***he - should - not see death***; and was not found, because God had translated him: for before his translation he had this testimony, that he pleased God...
>
> ...***These all died in faith***, not having received the promises, but having seen them afar off, and were persuaded of them, and embraced them, and confessed that they were strangers and pilgrims on the earth." Hebrews 11:5 & 13

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is it not the case that the writer, having clearly stated that Enoch did not see death, then excludes Enoch from the statement, "These all died," ?

It is unnecessary for the writer to break into the second statement and add "except for Enoch" as the writer has already excluded that singular circumstance by previously defining it separately.

Comment: Nijel - I think this is a logical argument, and reflects "plain meaning interpretations", (so +1).  However, the entire New Testament presupposes that the rational/logical inferences the elders made were entirely wrong. So, it would be more helpful if there are textual indications, (Greek or Hebrew), or any evidence that this phrase was ever used literally, or metaphorically.  Granted - if none of those evidences exist, then I think this answer would suffice.  So, I suppose this answer is an example of a vaild  **["argument from silence"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_from_silence)**.

Comment: Please elaborate on "the entire New Testament presupposes that the rational/logical inferences the elders made were entirely wrong". What elders?

Comment: @elikakohen No, it is not an 'argument from silence'. I have already pointed out that it is said, 'Enoch did not see death' _before_ it is stated, 'these all died in faith'. I do not understand the rest of your comment.

Comment: Enoch "did not see death" **when he was 65 years old**, because, he was relocated to walk with elohim elsewhere, for the final 300 years of his life. Genesis 5:22 is where the translation and then walking takes place **as clearly stated in that verse**. Genesis 5:24 being a restatement of that event. At the end of that further 300 years he died, on earth, as clearly stated in Genesis 5:23 "and ALL the days of Enoch were 365 years". Hence in Hebrews, he was faithful, he was translated (out of the hand of Lamech Genesis 4:23,24), then he walked with elohim, **then he died**, on earth (11:13).

Comment: @davidianwalker 'all the days of Enoch' does not speak of death. These were all the days he spent on earth - and then he was not (on earth) and his days could no longer be recorded (for he was not on earth, but elsewhere). This is all very simple and logical. I cannot understand why you have difficulty with it. (Unless the problem is a matter of unbelief.)

Comment: 'When Enoch had lived 65 years, he became the father of Methuselah. **After he became the father of Methuselah, Enoch walked faithfully with God 300 years** and had other sons and daughters. Altogether, Enoch lived a total of 365 years.' Genesis 5:21-23 ***This event is then re-stated*** being the outstanding feature of his life : 'Enoch walked faithfully with God; then he was no more, because God took him away.' ***Genesis 5:24 is a re-statement of verse 22***. **It didn't happen twice!** Sad.

Comment: @davidianwalker I think the matter is quite clear in scripture (old and new testaments) and I don't think I need to re-state anything. No further comment from myself on this matter.

Answer (score 3):

This question has not an answer plainly in scripture and without answering suggest a place to look. There were two that seemingly went to heaven before dying and they were Enoch in Genesis 5:24 and Elijah in 2 Kings 2:11.

We see in John 17:10-13 and Jesus said Elijah truly shall first come and restore all things 12 But I say unto you, that Elijah is come already and they new him not, but have done unto him whatever they listed.

Likewise shall also the Son of man suffer of them. We see in John 21:21-22 where Peter seemed he was to do more than john and Jesus said If I will that he tarry till I come what is that to thee follow thou me. In Revelations 10:8-11 when John was handed the little book and told to eat it.

The 11th verse the angel told him Thou must prophesy again before many peoples and nations and tongues and kings. I may be wrong but I do not believe that has happened. If I may suggest as Elijah's spirit was in John the Baptist maybe Enoch's spirit may be one of the two witnesses along with John.in Revelations 11

I hope this is not to far out there and I understand if this is rejected, but these questions  may not be able to be answered with references. But all will die from the first Adam. Luke 2:26 KJV And it was revealed unto him by the Holy Ghost that he should not ἰδεῖν θάνατον  horaó thanatos (see death) before he had seen the Lord’s Christ.

Heb.11:5 KJV By faith Enoch was translated that he should not ἰδεῖν θάνατον  horaó thanatos (see death)….

Here is one in  John 8:51 is same word for death but he shall never see θεωρήσῃ  theóreó more of an I behold, look at, experience.

Also in Ps. 89:48KJV What man is he that liveth , and shall not see death וְלֹ֣א wə-lō (no) יִרְאֶה־     yir-’eh- (see) מָּ֑וֶת mā-weṯ; (death)  I believe that Simeon in Luke is the match the Holy Ghost told him he would not die before he saw Jesus same wording as in Hebrews. I ‘m pretty sure that not see death is not to die. I don’t feel it is a contradiction just something’s harder to grab hold of. Enoch was taken up. Where?

Comment: Upvoted (+1) but may I suggest that you make paragraphs, as it helps to separate different points and is much easier on the eye than trying to read a 'wall of text'.

Answer (score 2):

(Note: I can’t give you what’s in the Book of Hebrews, so I'll just present this).

In Genesis 5, Enoch is the only father in the list of generations who doesn’t have wording such as “then he died” shown.  However, there are a couple of other things, in that chapter and elsewhere in Genesis, that lead me to believe he never died.

> **Gen 5:21-24 (NAB)** 
>   When Enoch was sixty-five years old, he became the father of Methuselah. 
>   22 Enoch lived three hundred years after the birth of Methuselah, and he had other sons and daughters. 23 The whole lifetime of Enoch was three hundred and sixty-five years. 24 Then Enoch walked with God, and he was no longer here, for God took him.

Enoch spent a lifetime of 365 years on earth.  ***Then*** he “walked with God… for God took him.”

In Genesis, there are only two people who “walked with God”.  Those are the two who had their lives saved.  Enoch “walked with God” just before God assumed him into heaven.  Noah was the only other person in Genesis who “walked with God”

> **Gen 6:9-10 (NAB)** 
>   These are the descendants of Noah. Noah was a righteous man and blameless in his generation; Noah walked with God. 10 Noah begot three sons: Shem, Ham, and Japheth.

Like Enoch, Noah’s life was saved; unlike Enoch though, God didn’t assume Noah into heaven and save his life permanently.  Instead, God saved Noah’s life temporarily; Noah “walked with God” just before he was allowed to survive the flood.  Yes, family members were allowed to survive the flood too, but that was because someone was needed to people the earth.

Comment: 'Enoch spent a lifetime of 365 years on earth. Then he “walked with God… for God took him.”'. Wrong! Wrong! Wrong! 'When Enoch had lived 65 years, he became the father of Methuselah. **After he became the father of Methuselah, Enoch walked faithfully with God 300 years** and had other sons and daughters. Altogether, Enoch lived a total of 365 years.' Genesis 5:21-23 This event is ***then re-stated*** being the outstanding feature of his life : 'Enoch walked faithfully with God; then he was no more, because God took him away.' Genesis 5:24 A re-statement of verse 22. **It didn't happen twice!**

Comment: Interpret it as you will. "Walk with God" might mean obeyed God and thus had his life saved (Enoch's permanently, unlike others, before the flood killed others...Noah's temporarily because he'd obeyed God and thus had his life saved from the flood). You're no one's teacher, just try your best as others here do.

Answer (score 2):

**ENOCH DID NOT GO TO HEAVEN,**

Jesus was in heaven when Enoch died and  he would have known if  he went to heaven. In view of Jesus clear statement at Jonn 3:13,

> ***"No one has ascended into heaven, but He who descended from heaven: the Son of Man."**(NASB)

- Enoch  certainly was not taken to heaven. God disposed of Enoch's body like He did for Moses for "he was nowhere to be found." (Deuteronomy 34:5,6 )

Enoch is one of the righteous servants of God  mentioned by Paul in his epistle to the Hebrews  ( chapter 11:5,13)  and who are still  awaiting the promise of resurrection. (John 5:28,29; Hebrews 11:26, 39,40)

Comment: The question was asked specifically to address the apparent contradiction. You have reasserted one side of the problem but not the other. How do you deal with the Hebrew's passage other than ignoring it? Or are you saying that he is still alive but hidden in a cave or something?

Answer (score 1):

Enoch, like Melchizedek appears briefly in Genesis and then does not reappear in the Protestant canon until "To the Hebrews". While less is said in Hebrews about Enoch than about Melchizedek much is written of Enoch in extra-biblical writings.

However, "the scrolls of Enoch" was an early apocalypse that was popular with Jews and Christians alike but not included in the Catholic or Protestant canons. It was quoted by NT writers and seems to have influenced many NT passages.

I'm too lazy to give an exhaustive report on the place of Enoch in this answer but I will point out that he was clearly understood to not have died and to have been transported directly into the sky, to where God and the angels are. In addition he is taken on a tour of the place of the dead and the prison of angels.

He also appears to be equated with Philo's logos and the messenger that accompanied Moses on the Exodus.

For further reading please consult:

http://jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/5772-enoch

http://jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/10736-metatron

http://biblehub.com/library/deane/pseudepigrapha/the_book_of_jubilees.htm

The one thing I do want to call attention to that is particularly relevant to the question at hand is Peter's cryptic reference to Enoch's preaching to the angels in prison in which he seems to be identifying Christ with Enoch!:

> NIV 1 Peter 3: 18For Christ also suffered once for sins, the righteous
>   for the unrighteous, to bring you to God. **He was put to death in the
>   body but made alive in the Spirit.** 19After being made alive, **he
>   went and made proclamation to the imprisoned spirits— 20to those who
>   were disobedient long ago when God waited patiently in the days of
>   Noah while the ark was being built.** In it only a few people, eight
>   in all, were saved through water,

This is a clear reference to the scrolls of Enoch:

> [Chapter 15] 1 And He answered and said to me, and I heard His voice:
>   'Fear not, Enoch, thou righteous 2 man and scribe of righteousness:
>   approach hither and hear my voice. **And go, say to the Watchers of
>   heaven, who have sent thee to intercede for them: "You should
>   intercede" for men, and not men 3 for you: Wherefore have ye left the
>   high, holy, and eternal heaven, and lain with women, and defiled
>   yourselves with the daughters of men and taken to yourselves wives,
>   and done like the children 4 of earth, and begotten giants (as your)
>   sons? And though ye were holy, spiritual, living the eternal life, you
>   have defiled yourselves with the blood of women, and have begotten
>   (children) with the blood of flesh, and, as the children of men, have
>   lusted after flesh and blood as those also do who die 5 and perish.
>   Therefore have I given them wives also that they might impregnate
>   them, and beget 6 children by them, that thus nothing might be wanting
>   to them on earth. But you were formerly 7 spiritual, living the
>   eternal life, and immortal for all generations of the world. And
>   therefore I have not appointed wives for you; for as for the spiritual
>   ones of the heaven, in heaven is their dwelling. 8 And now, the
>   giants, who are produced from the spirits and flesh, shall be called
>   evil spirits upon 9 the earth, and on the earth shall be their
>   dwelling. Evil spirits have proceeded from their bodies; because they
>   are born from men and from the holy Watchers is their beginning and
>   primal origin; 10 they shall be evil spirits on earth, and evil
>   spirits shall they be called. [As for the spirits of heaven, in heaven
>   shall be their dwelling, but as for the spirits of the earth which
>   were born upon the earth, on the earth shall be their dwelling.] And
>   the spirits of the giants afflict, oppress, destroy, attack, do
>   battle, and work destruction on the earth, and cause trouble: they
>   take no food, but nevertheless 12 hunger and thirst, and cause
>   offences. And these spirits shall rise up against the children of men
>   and against the women, because they have proceeded from them.**
>
> [Chapter 16] 1 From the days of the slaughter and destruction and
>   death of the giants, from the souls of whose flesh the spirits, having
>   gone forth, shall destroy without incurring judgement -thus shall they
>   destroy until the day of the consummation, the great judgement in
>   which the age shall be 2 consummated, over the Watchers and the
>   godless, yea, shall be wholly consummated." And now as to the watchers
>   who have sent thee to intercede for them, who had been aforetime in
>   heaven, (say 3 to them): "You have been in heaven, but all the
>   mysteries had not yet been revealed to you, and you knew worthless
>   ones, and these in the hardness of your hearts you have made known to
>   the women, and through these mysteries women and men work much evil on
>   earth." 4 Say to them therefore: " You have no peace."'
>
> [Chapter 21] ...Then I said: 'How 9 fearful is the place and how
>   terrible to look upon!' Then Uriel answered me, one of the holy angels
>   who was with me, and said unto me: 'Enoch, why hast thou such fear and
>   affright?' And 10 I answered: 'Because of this fearful place, and
>   because of the spectacle of the pain.' And he said unto me: 'This
>   place is the prison of the angels, and here they will be imprisoned
>   for ever.''

So I see every reason to believe that Hebrews, as well as Peter to have understood Enoch to have been transported to "heaven" and "descended into hell" and preached to the angels in Tartarus, the prison of angels, in the days of Noah.

Comment: The watchers were angels that sinned and were put into Tartarus. Peter mentions that elsewhere in his writings. I'm not at the keyboard right now.

Comment: I also should say that when I wrote that post I was under the impression that Enoch was older than it was. That I don't think can be shown. I had gotten some false information about it being found in qumran which appears to have been misinformation.

Answer (score 0):

Hebrews 11:5 does not actually say Enoch *did not die*. It says that he did not *see* death. I interpret this to mean Enoch never saw anyone die.

[Here is a graph showing the lifespans of early mankind](https://answersingenesis.org/bible-characters/ancient-patriarchs-in-genesis/).

Enoch was "taken up" when he was 365 years old. He was only 57 when Adam died at age 930. By this time, mankind had been spreading out through the land, and at the young age of 57, who knows what Enoch was doing when Adam died; or even how long it would have taken someone to deliver the news to him.

Seth wouldn't die for another 55 years after Enoch was taken, and since he was taken a few years before Noah was born, he was probably dead before the flood. Noah was 600 when the flood began, so Enoch would have been 1034, which was a very decent lifespan at this time. Enoch could have died a few years before the flood, and would still have outlived Adam's age.

Comment: @elikakohen I have actually looked up the instances of "see death" in the Scriptures. The closest I've found that uses the word ὁράω for "see" is Luke 2:26. I would have no problem interpreting this passage as physically seeing death, but I don't accept the first two chapters of Luke anyways. If you know of such a passage, please share and we can look at it. Who knows? Maybe Hebrews contradicts Yeshua and I should just get rid of it anyways. I like it too much though.

Comment: Thanks for the +1. I'm not sure if finding another example would help much. We're talking about a very unique situation. Also, the letter was written to the Jewish people, so I believe a Hebrew metaphor would be more appropriate. The only thing I can find is Psalm 89:48 "What man [*is he that*] liveth, and shall **not see death**? shall he deliver his soul from the hand of the grave? Selah." This may be a good separate question. Is this to be taken metaphorical, or does the psalmist mean "What man has lived but hasn't seen death? Can he even deliver his own soul from the hand of sheol?"

Comment: What is intended by "translated"?

Comment: For all those who are determined to believe that Enoch somehow never died and went to heaven, I would raise this question:  What did Enoch do that was so special and unique that spared him from dying, that none of the other patriarchs did?  All those righteous patriarchs listed in Hebrews 11 died, so we read, but not Enoch?  What was so special about Enoch?

Answer (score 0):

Peace.

Enoch did not die but was “translated”…that is, “transferred or transported”…to Heaven by God because God took him.

Enoch did not experience death and carries this testimony in the written Word for us today:  that he pleased God (he did walk with God).   We must also walk in the Spirit and put to death the deeds of the body so that we may please God.

> Hebrews 11:5 KJV (5)  ***By faith Enoch was translated that he should not
>   see death; and was not found, because God had translated him:*** for
>   before his translation he had this testimony, that he pleased God.

The rest in the list of the heroes of faith did die in faith (they are the “dead in Christ”).

> Hebrews 11:13 KJV (13)  *T**hese all died in faith, not having received
>   the promises,** but having seen them afar off, and were persuaded of
>   them, and embraced them, and confessed that they were strangers and
>   pilgrims on the earth.*

The rest who died in faith did not receive the “promises”…..the promise of eternal life in Jesus Christ and the promises made to Abraham.  This is the “promise” that He has promise us:  eternal life.

> 1 John 2:25-26 KJV (25)  ***And this is the promise that he hath promised
>   us, even eternal life.*** (26)  These things have I written unto you
>   concerning them that seduce you.

They did not receive the "promise"….the promise of eternal life… but saw it from afar as they expected (in faith) it in the coming of the Son to this earth… Jesus Christ.   The Son came into this world so that this world might have life. Yet, they died and had not received the promise of eternal life in this earth.

> Hebrews 11:39-40 KJV (39)  **And these all, having obtained a good
>   report through faith, received not the promise:**

Their testimonies in the Scriptures are to be interpreted by Christ (as opposed to the private interpretation of men who wrest the Scriptures) so that they without us should not be made complete.

We hear their voices ( as a roar of many “waters”) in the voice of the Lord who speaks their testimonies in the heavenly (from Heaven) interpretation of the Scriptures.

We are made complete by hearing and believing in the voice of the Son of God who comes to give us an understanding.  Those who believe in Him shall not perish from this earth (in mortal death) but have an everlasting life (the eternal life of Jesus that He is experiencing now).   We must raise Him and His testimony above all that are of the earth.   His heavenly testimony is above all of what men are preaching in the many churches.

> (40)  *God having provided some better thing for us, **that they without
>   us should not be made perfec**t.*

Enoch was the exception in that list of those who died in faith and shows us today what “eternal life” is….a life that pleases God so that we are also to be “translated” to Heaven without seeing death…just like Enoch.

Jesus already physically died for our sins so that we may not die but have His eternal life now in this earth.

In Genesis 3:22, we are told that the Tree of Life (Jesus) is the source of eternal life.

To live “forever” (Hebrew :  “olam”) is to live to the “ concealed…the vanishing point”…..just like Enoch who “vanished” from this earth for he was not.  Enoch was “not found” as he was transferred to Heaven without seeing death.

> Genesis 3:22 KJV (22)  *And the LORD God said, Behold, the man is
>   become as one of us, to know good and evil: and now, lest he put forth
>   his hand, **and take also of the tree of life, and eat, and live for
>   ever:***

Enoch “was not” as he lived to the “vanishing point” (he was not found) as God took him….transferring him to Heaven without seeing death.   This is the kind of way we want to go from this earth.

> Genesis 5:23-24 KJV (23*)  And all the days of Enoch were three hundred
>   sixty and five years: (24)  And Enoch walked with God: **and he was not;**
>   for God took him.*

Jesus already died for us at the cross….and so we are to participate in His death by dying to sin so that we might have His life now in this earth.

We keep His “daily” sacrifice always in our mortal bodies so that His eternal life is made manifest (shines) outward in our mortal flesh.  He gives His flesh for the life of the world….this world. We must also "walk with God"...through His Spirit that dwells in us.

> Romans 8:11-14 KJV (11)  *But if the Spirit of him that raised up Jesus
>   from the dead dwell in you, he that raised up Christ from the dead
>   **shall also quicken your mortal bodies by his Spirit that dwelleth in
>   you.***

The other way to Heaven is to physically die (to suffer loss) and it is never pleasant.  Why wish for the Day of the Lord’s wrath in which we are destroyed from this earth as the heavens come to get each of us with a “whirring” sound (2 Peter 3:10) ….with the sound of a whirlwind?

The wages of sin is death….death to the mortal body and then the spirit goes back to God who gave it.   We must put to death (through the Spirit of God) the deeds of the body so that we may receive the promise of eternal life....the life of Jesus.

> (12)  *Therefore, brethren, we are debtors, not to the flesh, to live
>   after the flesh. (13)  **For if ye live after the flesh, ye shall die:
>   but if ye through the Spirit do mortify the deeds of the body, ye
>   shall live**.*

We must walk with God…walking in His Spirit…being led by His Spirit...so that we may please Him thoroughly and some day be translated ("death" is ours) just as Enoch was.

> (14)  **For as many as are led by the Spirit of God,** they are the sons
>   of God.

But some may scoff and say where is the "promise" of His coming.....where is His promised eternal life in this earth?

Answer (score 0):

Bible neither claims that Enoch "lived" nor that he left the earth. It clearly and pointedly states *exactly the opposite* on both those counts :

> **ALL these died** in faith, without receiving the promises, but having seen and welcomed them from a distance, and having confessed that they were **strangers and exiles ON THE EARTH**.
>
> Hebrews 11:13 NASB
> *referring to Enoch in verse 5*

'... and Enoch walked (וַיִּתְהַלֵּ֨ךְ) with god ...' Genesis 5:22

'... and Enoch walked (וַיִּתְהַלֵּ֥ךְ) with god ...' Genesis 5:24

Elohim had walked or 'fellowshipped' with Adam and Eve in the garden :

> Then the man and his wife heard the sound of the Lord God as he was walking (מִתְהַלֵּ֥ךְ) in the garden in the cool of the day ...
>
> Genesis 3:8 NIV

Direct interaction between elohim and the faithful, and the wicked, was a feature after the ejection from Eden :

> *After he drove the man out*, he placed on the east side of the Garden of Eden **cherubim** and a flaming sword flashing back and forth *to guard the way* to the tree of life.
>
> Genesis 3:24 NIV

> Then the Lord said to Cain ...
>
> Then the Lord said to Cain ...
>
> Cain said to the Lord, “My punishment is more than I can bear. Today *you are driving me from the land*, and **I will be hidden from your presence** ..."
>
> Genesis 4:6,9,13-14 NIV

However this fellowship, or judgement, was withdrawn before the flood :

> Then the Lord said, “My Spirit will not contend with (or judge - יָד֨וֹן - as with Cain) humans forever, for they are mortal (בָשָׂ֑ר - corrupt); their days will be a hundred and twenty years.”
>
> Genesis 6:3 NIV

The tree of life being lost to us in this flood, the cherubim no longer being required.
Concomitantly, elohim became infrequent visitors.

'Enoch was translated ...' Hebrews 11:5

'... was not found because God had translated him ...' Hebrews 11:5

'... before the translation ...' Hebrews 11:5

Translation in this case - μεταθέσεως - indicates a geographical move. Same word in Acts 7:16 referencing the movement of human remains from Egypt to Shechem.

Moreover, the span of Enoch's life is clearly stated.

> And Enoch lived **65 years** - and begat Methusaleh ...
>
> ... and Enoch walked (there's that word 'fellowshipped') with God after he begat Methusaleh, **three hundred years** - and begat sons and daughters ...
>
> ... and ALL the days of Enoch were, **three hundred and sixty-five years** ...
>
> Genesis 5:21,22,23 Rotherham

After Enoch had produced the next heir in the line of Seth when he was 65 years old, his participation in that process no longer being necessary, he was 'translated' or moved away from that environment, to a location not specified, where from that point on, he walked or 'fellowshipped' with elohim as Adam and Eve had, and so lived out the remainder of his days, being another 300 years, in which time he had further sons and daughters.

I don't even know how anyone could even accidentally miss all those "words" ...

Why?

Witness protection elohim style.

Lines of Cain and Seth.

> Woe to them! They have taken **the way of Cain** ... Enoch, **the seventh from Adam**, prophesied about them ... and of *all the defiant words* ... *they boast about themselves and flatter others for their own advantage*.
>
> Jude 1:11,14,15,16 NIV

**Enoch**, *seventh from Adam* via Seth - Genesis 5
Lamech, *seventh from Adam* via **Cain** - Genesis 4:16-18

'... *all the defiant words* ... *they boast about themselves and flatter others for their own advantage* ...' :

> Lamech said to his wives, “Adah and Zillah, **listen to me**; wives of Lamech, **hear my words**. I *have killed* (הָרַ֙גְתִּי֙) a man for wounding me, a young man for injuring me. If **Cain** is avenged seven times, then Lamech seventy-seven times.”
>
> Genesis 4:23,24 NIV

The AKJV has a marginal reference for "*have killed*" being "**would** kill".
From elsewhere :

> I **would** certainly *have killed* (הָרַ֖גְתִּי) you by now ...
>
> Numbers 22:33 NIV

These are **defiant words** and nothing else.

It's Genesis 3:15 playing out. There being a distinct separation of those that obeyed elohim - styled the sons or children of god, and those that followed the way of Cain.
That distinct division being punctuated by violence and ultimately broken in Genesis 6 (verses 1 through 8) with regard to intermarriage. Hence god's disappointment and final judgement.
This entropy further increasing in the threefold division after the flood in the descendents of Noah and the scattering at the tower.

> **ALL these died** in faith, without receiving the promises, but having seen and welcomed them from a distance, and having confessed that they were **strangers and exiles ON THE EARTH**.
>
> Hebrews 11:13 NASB
> *referring to Enoch in verse 5*

Died in faith when he turned up his feet, and not by the hand of Lamech 300 years earlier in spite of his boast.
Moved, out of harms way, away from the grasp of a man who would recompense the wounding he inherited from Cain, on the line of Seth.

> Enoch was translated, so as *not to see death*, and was *not found*, because that, God, had translated him ...
>
> Hebrews 11:5 Rotherham

Was *not found **by Lamech*** and therefore did *not see death **by the hand of Lamech*** at that time.

I have to assume the scapegoat for this oversight is the repetition of the distinctive feature of Enoch's life provided as summary.

> ... **and Enoch walked with God**,––and was not, for God had taken him.
>
> Genesis 5:24 Rotherham

The casual reader perhaps concluding that at the end of Enoch's life he walked with god.
However, this is clearly a revisiting of earlier events :

> And Enoch lived 65 years - and begat Methusaleh ...
>
> ... **and Enoch walked with God after he begat Methusaleh**, three hundred years - and begat sons and daughters ...
>
> ... and all the days of Enoch were, three hundred and sixty-five years ...
>
> Genesis 5:21,22,23 Rotherham

A plain, unambiguous record of the pertinent features of his life and then a declaration of death.

This distinctive feature of his life provided in summary not only in Genesis but also in Hebrews. In both cases the summary or refrain belonging to the events immediately following his fathering Methusaleh.
Indicated by :

'... **and Enoch walked with God, after he begat Methuselah**, three hundred years,––and begat sons and daughters ...' Genesis 5:22

'... **and Enoch walked with God**,––and was not, for God had taken him.' Genesis 5:24

This verse 24 being a **summary**.
To suggest otherwise is to suggest that Enoch was translated **twice**.

Genesis and Hebrews agree in these matters.

> And Enoch lived, sixty–five years,––and begat Methuselah ...
>
> ... for, before the translation, he had received witness that he had become well–pleasing unto (or *rendered service to* - εὐαρεστηκέναι) God ...
>
> Genesis 5:21, Hebrews 11:5 Rotherham

> ... and Enoch walked with God, after he begat Methuselah, three hundred years,––and begat sons and daughters ...
>
> Enoch was translated, so as not to see death *(at that time)*, and was not found *(by Lamech who consequently, was unable to make good on his threat)*, because that, God, had translated him ...
>
> ... and Enoch walked with God,––and was not, for God had taken him.
>
> Genesis 5:22, Hebrews 11:5, Genesis 5:24 Rotherham
> *verse 24 being a **re-statement** of verse 22 as **the defining feature** of his life*

> ... and **all** the days of Enoch were, three hundred and sixty–five years ...
>
> ... **all these died**––***not** bearing away the promises*, but, from afar, beholding and saluting them, and confessing that, strangers and sojourners, were they upon the land (or earth - γῆς)   .
>
> Genesis 5:23, Hebrews 11:13 Rotherham

> ... sin entered the world through one man, and death through sin, and in this way **death came to all people**, because all sinned ...
>
> ... **death reigned from the time of Adam to the time of Moses** ...
>
> Romans 5:12,14 NIV

This Enoch stuff is a nonsense. Always has been and always will be.

Comment: This would be a much better answer if it were trimmed down a lot. ¶ The basic argument is: — Genesis 5:24 says "*God took him*", a common euphemism for "he died".
— Hebrews 11:5 says Enoch was "translated".
— Acts 7:15–16 uses the same Greek word to say that Jacob's body was "translated" to the city of Sychem and put into a sepulchre.
— No scripture in the Bible mentions or even implies that Enoch went to Heaven.
— Any interpretation that mentions Heaven is purely eisegesis, especially in light of Hebrews 11:13 and John 3:13.

Comment: Maybe but the voice of scripture is getting lost in the blasphemy, suggesting Enoch lived or went to heaven is clearly not biblical, and heresy, as deliberate - this is not mere laziness. I don't frame answers for blasphemers and heretics but for those seeking clarification. Clarification "God took him" is not a euphemism for "he died". That's kind of the point. Took him and **then later after the taking** he died. On earth. Genesis and Hebrews agree on this. The *translating* and *walking* happened after he begat Methusaleh, after which he then lived a further 300 years and died, on earth.