# Does Hebrews 13:8 verse evidence that sins of Enoch and Elijah are cleared by Jesus Christ's death?

Tags: hebrews, sin, death, atonement

It used to confuse me as to how Elijah's and Enoch's "rapture" ( for lack of a better term to describe that they did Not die a physical death on earth ) happened before Jesus Christ's death by crucifixion on the cross.

> **Genesis 5:21-24 (NASB)**
>   21 Enoch lived sixty-five years, and became the father of Methuselah. 22 Then Enoch walked with God three hundred years after he became the father of Methuselah, and he had other sons and daughters. 23 So all the days of Enoch were three hundred and sixty-five years. 24 Enoch walked with God; and he was not, for God took him.
>
> **2 Kings 2:11 (NASB)**
>   11 As they were going along and talking, behold, there appeared a chariot of fire and horses of fire which separated the two of them. And Elijah went up by a whirlwind to heaven.

However, would it be correct to view Jesus Christ's death on the cross as something that is more than just happening at a particular point of instance in time?  To elaborate, would it be correct to view the following Hebrews 13:8 verse as evidence that Jesus Christ's death on the cross covers the sins of Enoch and Elijah?

> **Hebrews 13:8 (NASB)**
>   8 Jesus Christ is the same yesterday and today and forever.

Comment: I think I know what you are asking and would look forward to answering it but I think that as asked your question is more theology than exegesis. Hebrews 13:8 is not about anyone's justification. Please write an exegetical question on the same subject as I think I can clear up your confusion.

Comment: Revelation 13:8 '...the Lamb slain _from the foundation of the world_. His is the only sacrifice that can take away sins and his sacrifice is that which applies to _all_ God's people, whatever time they lived in.

Comment: What sins of Enoch and Elijah?  Granted that Jesus is the same always, but I see His role/insertion/involvement as progressive, culminating in the Crucifixion and Resurrection - opening the way to Forgiveness for all (rather than selective).

Comment: @tblue Jesus said, himself _for if ye believe not that I am he, ye shall die in your sins_. [John 8:24](http://textusreceptusbibles.com/Interlinear/43008024). This appears to me to be, conclusively, selective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reference: [How can John 3:13-14 be reconciled with what happened to Enoch, Elijah and Jesus?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/11451/how-can-john-313-14-be-reconciled-with-what-happened-to-enoch-elijah-and-jesus)

**@joseph states:

> Jesus was **Not** the first mortal man to enter heaven, since Elijah and
>   Enoch (and perhaps Moses as well) had entered heaven before Jesus.
>   However, Jesus was the first immortal man to enter heaven, because his
>   immortality stemmed from his eternal life, which had become flesh when
>   He descended from heaven to earth. The PERSON subsequently died on the
>   cross in both the spiritual and physical sense, and so He descended to
>   the lower parts of the earth and then was "raised up" like the bronze
>   serpent to be the savior of man. That is, He was the first, "firstborn
>   from the dead" to ever ascend into heaven and take His seat at the
>   right hand of the Almighty, and in this sense, ...no one has ascended
>   into heaven, but He who descended from heaven: the Son of Man.

**

Comment: If the 'spiritual' 'Person' 'died' what was it that descended to the lower parts of the earth ? When a body dies, the _soul_ descends.